# Add to an array the content generated by a foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

i display with a foreach the content of a user_meta in wordpress. It displays input taht fills with the values (so they can be changed). I want to be able to store each content in a new array (so i can update the user_meta next.

So here is the main code :

```
    <?php

function edit_profile_form() {

    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $data = get_user_meta ($current_user_id);

    if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
        delete_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['button1'])) {
        save_extra_profile_fields($current_user_id);
    };

    $experiences = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences', true);

?>

<div class="container_form">
<form method="POST">

    <h3>Vos expériences</h3>

    <div class="experiences_container">
        <?php 
        if (!empty($experiences)) {
            $index=0;
            foreach ($experiences as $key) {
            $index++;
            echo($index);
            echo($key);
            ?>
                <div class="past_experience">
                    <div class="experience_header">
                        <div>
                            <label for="team">Nom de l'équipe</label>
                                <input class="team" name="team" value="<?= $key['new_experience_team'];?>"/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="role">Rôle dans l'équipe</label>
                                <input class="role" name="role" value="<?= $key['new_experience_role'];?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="experience_textarea">
                        <label for="description">Description du rôle</label>
                        <textarea class="description" name="description"><?= $key['new_experience_description']; ?></textarea>

                        <label for="palmares">Palmarés avec l'équipe</label>
                        <textarea class="palmares" name="palmares"><?= $key['new_experience_palmares']; ?></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>  
            <?php
            } 

        } else {
        ?>
        <div><p>Vous n'avez encore rentré aucune expérience</p></div>
        <?php 
    }?>


    </div>

    <div class="add_container">
        <div id="dropdown">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-square" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>
            <p id="show" onClick="dropdown()" >Ajouter une expérience</p>
        </div>
        <div id="experience" style="display:none;">

            <label for="new_experience_team">Nom de l'équipe</label>
            <input type="text" name="experiences[new_experience_team]" id="experience_team">

            <label for="new_experience_role">Rôle dans l'équipe</label>
            <input type="text" name="experiences[new_experience_role]" id="experience_role">

            <label for="new_experience_description">Description du poste</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="experiences[new_experience_description]" id="experience_description"></textarea>

            <label for="new_experience_palmares">Palmarés</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="experiences[new_experience_palmares]" id="experience_palmares"></textarea>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="button_container">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Sauvegarder" id='save'/>
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Annuler"/>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
```

The function's one :

```
<?php

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if (!empty($_POST['experiences'])) {
        $savedexperience = get_user_meta($user_id, 'experiences', true);
        if (!empty($savedexperience) && is_array($savedexperience )) {
            $experiences = $savedexperience;
        }
        $experiences[] = $_POST['experiences'];
        update_usermeta($user_id, 'experiences', $experiences);
    }
}
```

So i want to be able to stock in a array each group of team, role, description and palmares.

I don't know if it's clear at all :/

Thanks all

Comment: It's not really clear. Can you post the code where you handle the submitted form ?

Comment: Yup, i update the post

Comment: It's done, i have another file that just create a shortcode to paste the form in Wordpress, not interesting one i swear. Finally i want to update the $experiences variable (with all the new content of the foreach) that is actually just updating with added experience (the dropdown form).

Comment: Could you please trim all unneeded code? Like divs which dont matter. The result will become smaller, easier to read and more inviting to get help :)

Comment: Might be better :) The final result of experiences might be the updated info of the foreach created div and the experience add through add_container :)

Comment: If I understand your code you want to merge saved experiences with new ones received from the form ?

Comment: Hum yes but in the form i have the saved one that can be edited (in the foreach) and the new ones (in the class='add_container'). For the moment i can add new one but when i edit the one in the foreach, it does not save.